# Roslyn - SyntaxFactory - Parse Statement - Add Carriage Return / New Line?

Tags: roslyn

I'm creating a class using Roslyn. Just like this 
*https://gist.github.com/cmendible/9b8c7d7598f1ab0bc7ab5d24b2622622*

How do you add Carriage Returns to the body (ParseStatement). I have tried adding NewLine(), SyntaxFactory.CarriageReturn. Nothing seems to work or get generated.

SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement - puts everything on the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue regarding this logged @ https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/202.  New lines apparently are removed automatically.

For now it ignores any new line type characters anyway.